# VBNC not compile with Linq function

Tags: vb.net, linq, mono, xamarin

I want to use linq and vb.net with vbnc compiler.

When I try to compile this code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class Application
    Public Shared Sub Main()

      Dim lista As New List(Of String)
      lista.Add("Uno")
      lista.Add("Due")
      lista.Add("Tre")
      lista.Add("Quattro")

      Dim source = From elem As String In lista Where elem = "Uno" select elem
      System.Console.WriteLine("Hello world!")

  End Sub

End Class
```

I have the following error:

```
Error VBNC30205: Expected end of statement.
```

I think that vbnc compiler doesn't support linq function.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Have you referenced `System.Core`?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the cast in the statement; it shouldn't be needed:

```
Dim source = From elem In lista Where elem = "Uno" select elem
```

Comment: unfortunately, during Xamarin chat, Xamarin Team has confirmed that VBNC compiler do not support LINQ syntax.